# Product measure and integrals of simple functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_1 , \mathcal{X}, \mu)$ and $(\Omega_2 , \mathcal{Y}, \nu)$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and let $\mu \times \nu$ be product measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ (i.e., $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the measurable rectangles).

Let  $X$ be a Banach space (not necessarily separable), and suppose that $s : \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \to X$ is a simple function. By definition, this means that $s(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^N e_i \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(x,y)$, where each $e_i \in X$, and each $A_i \in \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ with $\mu \times \nu(A_i) < \infty$.

> I would like to show that the function $x \mapsto \int_{\Omega_2} s(x,y) d \nu(y)$ is also a simple function $\Omega_1 \to X$.

I am studying a proof of Fubini's theorem for the Bochner integral, and this fact is asserted. However, I have had a lot of trouble proving it. Here is my attempt so far:

If we fix $x \in X$ then $s(x, \cdot) = \sum_{i=1}^N e_i \mathbf{1}_{\{y| (x,y) \in A_i\}}(\cdot).$ Now, from the basic principles of product measure, we know that each $\{y| (x,y) \in A_i\} \in \mathcal{Y}$ ($i = 1, \dots, N$). Hence, it appears that the map $s(x, \cdot) \Omega_2 \to X$ is simple (although we still need to show that each $\nu (\{y| (x,y) \in A_i\}) < \infty$, and I'm not quite sure how to do this).

So finally, we can compute (for $x \in X$): 
$$\int_{\Omega_2} s(x,y) d \nu(y) = \sum_{i=1}^N e_i \mathbf{1}_{\{y| (x,y) \in A_i\}}(y) d\nu(y) = \sum_{i=1}^N e_i \nu(\{y| (x,y) \in A_i\}).$$

But it is not clear to me how $\sum_{i=1}^N e_i \nu(\{y| (x,y) \in A_i\})$ can be represented as a simple function.

One thing I have noticed is that, if we introduce a stronger assumption on the $A_i$, and require them to be measurable rectangles $A_i = C_i \times D_i$ ($C_i \in \mathcal{X}$, $D_i \in \mathcal{Y}$), then we will find that

$$\int_{\Omega_2} s(x,y) d \nu(y) = \sum_{i=1}^N e_i \nu(D_i) \mathbf{1}_{C_i}.$$

So we get a simple function in that situation.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @PVAL - This counterexample you give is convincing. I must be misunderstanding the the statement in the proof that I am reading, or it is simply wrong.

Comment: Which book are you reading?

Comment: I upgraded my comment to an answer, so the question can be closed. It seems this question is just about this statement and if you would like to ask about say references to the Fubini theorem for the Bochner integral or about the general method of proof it would be beneficial to do it in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Ω_i=[0,1]$, and $f$ be the characteristic function of a right triangle with hypotenuse the diagonal and an edge along $Ω_1×0$. Clearly your function is not a simple function in this case, it is just $h(x)=x$.